# Pig: Get index in nested foreach

Tags: apache-pig

I have a pig script with code like :

```
scores = LOAD 'file' as (id:chararray, scoreid:chararray, score:int);
scoresGrouped = GROUP scores by id;
top10s = foreach scoresGrouped{
    sorted = order scores by score DESC;
    sorted10 = LIMIT sorted 10;
    GENERATE group as id, sorted10.scoreid as top10candidates;
};
```

It gets me a bag like

```
 id1, {(scoreidA),(scoreidB),(scoreIdC)..(scoreIdFoo)}
```

However, I wish to include the index of items as well, so I'd have results like

```
 id1, {(scoreidA,1),(scoreidB,2),(scoreIdC,3)..(scoreIdFoo,10)}
```

Is it possible to include the index somehow in the nested foreach, or would I have to write my own UDF to add it in afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For indexing elements in a bag you may use the [Enumerate](http://linkedin.github.com/datafu/docs/javadoc/datafu/pig/bags/Enumerate.html) UDF from LinkedIn's [DataFu](http://data.linkedin.com/opensource/datafu) project:

```
register '/path_to_jar/datafu-0.0.4.jar';
define Enumerate datafu.pig.bags.Enumerate('1');
scores = ...
...
result = foreach top10s generate id, Enumerate(top10candidates);
```

Comment: I found the Enumerate udf to be really hard to use. For instance, Enumerate(STRSPLITTOBAG(myStr, '\\|', 0)) always results in null pointer error.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a UDF, whose only argument is the sorted bag you want to add a rank to.  I've had the same need before.  Here's the exec function to save you a little time:

```
public DataBag exec(Tuple b) throws IOException {
    try {
        DataBag bag = (DataBag) b.get(0);
        Iterator<Tuple> it = bag.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Tuple t = (Tuple)it.next();
            if (t != null && t.size() > 0 && t.get(0) != null) {
                t.append(n++);
            }
            newBag.add(t);
        }
    } catch (ExecException ee) {
        throw ee;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        int errCode = 2106;
        String msg = "Error while computing item number in " + this.getClass().getSimpleName();
        throw new ExecException(msg, errCode, PigException.BUG, e);           
    }

    return newBag;
}
```

(The counter `n` is initialized as a class variable outside the `exec` function.)

You can also implement the [Accumulator interface](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/writing_udfs.html), which will allow you to do this even if your entire bag won't fit in memory. (The COUNT built-in function does this.)  Just be sure to set `n = 1L;` in the `cleanup()` method and `return newBag;` in `getValue()`, and everything else is the same.