# Apache Pig: Join records by shifting

Tags: join, apache-pig

I have records of type:

```
time | url
==========
34 google.com 
42 cnn.com
54 yahoo.com
64 fb.com
```

I want to add another column to these records `time_diff` which basically takes the difference of the time of the current record with the previous record. Output should look like:

```
time | url | time_diff
======================
34 google.com -- <can drop this row>
42 cnn.com    08
54 yahoo.com  12
64 fb.com     10
```

If I can somehow add another column (same as `time`) shifting the `time` by one such that 42 is aligned with 34, 54 is aligned with 42 and so on, then I can take the difference between these columns to calculate `time_diff` column.

I can project the `time` column to a new variable `T` and if I can drop the first record in the original data, then I can join it with `T` to obtain the desired result.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that you would have multiple rows with the same time?  If so, what determines their order?

Comment: Time is in non-decreasing order (yes multiple rows can have the same time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984701/pig-get-index-in-nested-foreach), for example.  You'll need to get your tuples in a bag (using `GROUP ... ALL` in your case), and then in a nested `FOREACH`, `ORDER` them and call a UDF to rank them.  After you have this rank, you can `FLATTEN` the bag back out into a set of tuples again, and you'll have three fields: `time`, `url`, and `rank`.  Once you have this, create a fourth column which is `rank-1`, do a self-join on those latter two columns, and you'll have what you need to compute the `time_diff`.

Since multiple records can have the same `time`, it would be a good idea to also sort on `url` so that you are guaranteed the same result every time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "lead" function of PiggyBank. Something like following might work.

```
 A = LOAD 'T';

 B = GROUP A ALL

 C = FOREACH B {
     C1 = ORDER A BY d;
     GENERATE FLATTEN(Stitch(C1, Over(C1.time, 'lead')));
 }

 D = FOREACH C
    GENERATE stitched::time AS time,
            stitched::url AS url,
            stitched::time - $3 AS time_diff;
```

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/Over.html